# Русский до 1914 г., употребления "не". Нюансы при отрицании

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, частица-не, точное-словоупотребление

Из А. К. Толстого, произведение "Упырь".
Некоторые детали к смерти Прасковьи Андреевны:

> ...все полагали, что она себя отравила, и, со всем почтением к памяти
> покойницы, нельзя не думать, что это предположение справедливо.

Вопрос: мне, как иностранцу, хотелось бы понять эту фразу проще! *Подозревали, что отравилась*, или же *не подозревали*, или же *даже не подозревали такого*?

Так было ли отравление причиной смерти этой дамы (Прасковья Андреевна), или оно только как версия?

Answer (score 3):

Близким по смыслу будет такой вариант предложения:

*Все полагали, что она себя отравила, и, со всем почтением к памяти покойницы, **нельзя исключить версию**, что это  справедливо.*

Таким образом, версия отравления (она себя отравила) **весьма вероятна** (если все так полагали), но всё же это только версия, а не точно установленный факт.

Comment: Действительно, Очень Вам благодарен ! У этого автора как мне кажется фразы таковы,что до предела "заворачивают" разум. Даже после того как уж можеш понять разные там выкрутасы с ятями и без в сочетании с устаревшими оборотами и  прочими азами Гражданского алфавита

Answer (score 2):

"Нельзя не думать" ≈ "можно думать" (по коннотации не совсем равно, но ошибки не будет в таком переложении).

Если упростить это предложение Толстого, то выйдет так:

> **Все полагали, что она себя отравила, и, несмотря на почтение к памяти покойницы, можно думать, что это предположение справедливо.**